# How can I add CSS to FB feed dialog?

Tags: facebook, fbdialogs

I am new to facebook API. I've integrated feed dialog successfully. I want to add some CSS to feed dialog. How can I load a FB feed dialog in a **DIV** tag so that I can add some text above the FB dialog. (For ex: text like share it with your friends... and some instructions)

To display the feed dialog I've used JavaScript SDK. Below is the code...

```
FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          name: 'Feed dialog',
          link: 'http://testmysite.com',
          display: 'iframe'
          }function(response) {
            if (response && response.post_id) {
                alert("successful");
            });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Dialogs are not customizable in this fashion. From [Facebook's documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/) (*emphasis mine*):

> Dialogs provide a simple, **consistent** interface to display dialogs to users.

You might want to create your own dialog and use the appropriate [Facebook Graph API calls](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#feed) to post to a user's feed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot style Facebook ui elements, such as the like button share button, ui dialog etc. You can only customize the ui through the parameters Facebook provides you. For the full list of parameters look https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/. A quick look, and I dont think you can customize the text on the ui dialog.

Hope this helps,

Tyrone